# creating mysite dynamically

Tags: 2010

i would like to know how to dynamically create a personal site without redirecting the user to /_layouts/mysite.aspx?

The requirement is this:
 - create a list in the user's private mysite (MySite - Contents - List)
   - if mysite is not yet created, create mysite as in /_layouts/mysite.aspx

hopefully somebody can help me with this...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this script](https://serverfault.com/questions/145410/pre-provision-mysite-user-site-via-script/145489#145489) to pre-provision MySites.

Please note: I haven't tested this script, just posting it as an idea.

Comment: thanks toni, i'll try this...
btw, is there a way to do it directly on the code behind?

Comment: Yes, you could use the same code and rewrite it for .NET

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is that a user's mysite has a list in it when the user first accesses it, I say go with FeatureStapling. Create a (Web scoped) feature that creates your ListInstance (and if list = custom, the List definition of course), then create another (Farm scoped) feature that staples your list instance feature to the SPSPERS#0 site definition:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="GUIDOFLISTFEATURE" TemplateName="SPSPERS#0" />
</Elements>
```